# How do I fix this easy SQL calculation from 2 different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

this is an incredibly easy equation, since I am new to learning SQL. So I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE installs (
    date DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    spend INT,
    installs INT
);

INSERT INTO installs VALUES ('2016-08-01', 5000, 1000);
INSERT INTO installs VALUES ('2016-08-02', 1000, 2500);
INSERT INTO installs VALUES ('2016-08-03', 7500, 2000);
INSERT INTO installs VALUES ('2016-08-04', 15000, 4000);

CREATE TABLE Cohort_LTV (
    date DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    cohort_size INT,
    ltv_d365 DECIMAL(3,2)
    );

INSERT INTO Cohort_LTV VALUES ('2016-08-01', 1000, 5.00);
INSERT INTO Cohort_LTV VALUES ('2016-08-02', 2500, 3.00);
INSERT INTO Cohort_LTV VALUES ('2016-08-03', 2000, 2.50);
INSERT INTO Cohort_LTV VALUES ('2016-08-04', 400, 4.00);
```

How would I be able to calculate the equation cohort_size & ltv_d365 / installs.spend on August 3, 2016?

Here is my current equation:

```
SELECT (cohort_ltv.cohort_size * cohort_ltv.ltv_d365) / installs.spend
FROM installs
LEFT JOIN cohort_LTV
ON installs.date = cohort_LTV.date
WHEN date = '2016-08-03' 
;
```

I am getting an ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; error. I also realized that the calculation isn't coming out correctly without the WHEN date. Could someone please let me know where my code is wrong and how I can fix it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. Used where condition instated of WHEN.
2. When you join two tables then your write column name with table name.

tableName.ColumnName

example :
installs.date

```
SELECT (cohort_ltv.cohort_size * cohort_ltv.ltv_d365) / installs.spend 
FROM installs LEFT JOIN cohort_LTV ON installs.date = cohort_LTV.date 
WHERE installs.date = '2016-08-03'
```

Comment: Ohhhh makes sense now, I knew I was missing something in the details. Thank you so much!!